# Node/Express server starts before variable sets

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express

There is an issue on my node/express server startup in that it loads the server before the IP address function/script, which dynamically retrieves the hostIp from EC2 finishes. So my calls to a backend are all returning `undefined`.

Example: (search.js)

```
const awsHost = require('./host.js');

const hostIp = awsHost.getBackendHost();
const host = `http://${ hostIp }:1234`;
console.log(host);
console.log(hostIp);
console.log(awsHost.getBackendHost());
```

Output:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node src/index.js`
http://undefined:1234
undefined
Server: Success -port 1111
11.123.456.789
```

Here is the current state of my (index.js):

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('./web/'));
app.listen(1111, () => console.info('Server: Success -port 1111'));

require('./routes/routes.js')(app);

module.exports = app;
```

How can I force Node to run the `awsHost.getBackendHost()` function and load it before the final server start?

EDIT (host.js):

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

aws.config.update({ region: 'REGION' });

const getBackendHost = () => {
const ecs = new aws.ECS();
const ec2 = new aws.EC2();

const backendPort = '1234';
const clusterParameters = {
  cluster: 'CLUSTER',
};

ecs.listContainerInstances(clusterParameters, (listContainerError, listContainerData) => {
  if (listContainerError) console.log(listContainerError, listContainerError.stack);
  else {
    const containerInstanceParameters = {
      cluster: clusterParameters.cluster,
      containerInstances: listContainerData.containerInstanceArns
    };
    ecs.describeContainerInstances(containerInstanceParameters, (describeContainerError, describeContainerData) => {
      if (describeContainerError) console.log(describeContainerError, describeContainerError.stack);
      else {
        describeContainerData.containerInstances.forEach((container) => {
          container.remainingResources.forEach((dataSet) => {
            if (dataSet.stringSetValue && dataSet.stringSetValue.includes(backendPort)) {
              const containerInstanceId = {
                InstanceIds: [
                  container.ec2InstanceId
                ]
              };
              ec2.describeInstances(containerInstanceId, (describeInstanceError, describeInstanceData) => {
                if (describeInstanceError) console.log(describeInstanceError, describeInstanceError.stack);
                else {
                  const iP = describeInstanceData.Reservations[0].Instances[0].PrivateIpAddress;
                  console.log(iP);
                  return iP;
                }
                return describeInstanceError;
              });
            }
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }
 });
};

module.exports = {
  getBackendHost
};
```

Comment: Some js-inspecific approaches to service discovery might interest you.  You could find the host before you started the app, then pass it as an environment variable or config setting.  You could use DNS to point to the host so the config was always the same.  I'll let a js person explain the possible in code solution, which I suspect would be to defer the server startup to a callback for `awsHost.getBackendHost()`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @DanFarrell, I'll most likely need a callback, and have tried out something similar to your idea already. I do not have means to change the DNS, but I know how to get the IP every time, even if it changes.

Comment: Show "host.js", specifically, the `getBackendHost` function.  It looks like you aren't waiting for the Promise that function returns to resolve.  We won't know without seeing the function though.

Comment: @zero298 Added host.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually follow the callback convention that your API is suggesting.  The node AWS API uses node style error-first callbacks to do asynchronous calls.  You need to wait for those calls to finish.

Change your `getBackendHost()` to accept a callback: `function(err, host){...}` or Promisify it.  Then in your application, wait for the call to finish and use the callback to set the host correctly.

Additionally, the nested `forEach` sections need to also be rewritten with asynchronisity in mind.

It will resemble this:

```js
// host.js
const aws = require("aws-sdk");

aws.config.update({
  region: "REGION"
});

/*
 * Expect a node style callback of the signature:
 * function(err, ip){...}
 */
function getBackendHost(cb) {
  const ecs = new aws.ECS();
  const ec2 = new aws.EC2();

  const backendPort = "1234";
  const clusterParameters = {
    cluster: "CLUSTER"
  };

  ecs.listContainerInstances(clusterParameters, (listContainerError, listContainerData) => {
    // Bail from error
    if (listContainerError) return cb(listContainerError, null);

    const containerInstanceParameters = {
      cluster: clusterParameters.cluster,
      containerInstances: listContainerData.containerInstanceArns
    };

    ecs.describeContainerInstances(containerInstanceParameters, (describeContainerError, describeContainerData) => {
      // Bail from error
      if (describeContainerError) return cb(describeContainerError, null);


      /*
       * You will also need to rewrite this because you are iterating over async items and still not waiting for them
       */
      describeContainerData.containerInstances.forEach(container => {
        container.remainingResources.forEach(dataSet => {
          if (dataSet.stringSetValue && dataSet.stringSetValue.includes(backendPort)) {
            const containerInstanceId = {
              InstanceIds: [
                container.ec2InstanceId
              ]
            };
            ec2.describeInstances(containerInstanceId, (describeInstanceError, describeInstanceData) => {
              // Bail from error
              if (describeInstanceError) return cb(describeInstanceError, null);

              return cb(null, describeInstanceData.Reservations[0].Instances[0].PrivateIpAddress);
            });
          }
        });
      });
    });
  });
}

module.exports = {
  getBackendHost
};

// index.js
const awsHost = require('./host.js');

const hostIp = awsHost.getBackendHost(function(err, hostIp) {
  // Bail from error
  if (err) return console.error(err);

  const host = `http://${ hostIp }:1234`;
  console.log(host);
  console.log(hostIp);
  console.log(awsHost.getBackendHost());
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I followed a guide about making async loops here: https://blog.lavrton.com/javascript-loops-how-to-handle-async-await-6252dd3c795 and ended up making two separate handlers for the looping.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to do a solution outside of NodeJS I'd recommend wrapping your startup in a promise. Possibly doing something like this:

```
const curl = new (require( 'curl-request' ))();

curl
.get('http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4')
.then(({statusCode, body, headers}) => {
    console.log(statusCode, body, headers);
    // start express here
})
.catch((err) => {
    throw err;
});
```

The IP address of the ec2 will be the body of this request.

Edit:

Regarding the 169.254.169.254 IP address, it's an AWS service that is available from EC2 instances. By using curl or wget on that IP it will always return metadata about the instance that made the request.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-retrieval

Comment: Thank you for the response, however, the problem with my environment is that I don't know the IP address until I make the call to my script function. I understand using a promise, but a curl request wont exactly work here...

Comment: The 169.254.169.254 is an AWS service, not the IP of your instance. It will always return metadata about the instance where the query originated from.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-data-retrieval